# AWS CDK - Stack set operation was unexpectedly stopped or failed

Tags: typescript, aws-cdk

I would like to deploy two roles in multiple OUs with a Stack Set. The error message is:" Stack set operation was unexpectedly stopped or failed.", which doesn't help me.

Here's my code:

```
new CfnStackSet(this, "RoleTest", {

        stackSetName: "StackSetTest",
        permissionModel: "SERVICE_MANAGED",
        autoDeployment: {
            enabled: true,
            retainStacksOnAccountRemoval: false
        },
        stackInstancesGroup: [{
            deploymentTargets: {
                organizationalUnitIds: ["OU1","OU2"]
            },
            regions: ["eu-central-1"]
        }]
```

I left out the templateBody because it was just copy and pasted from a working StackSet. Can somebody guess the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved my problem. First i was missing the parameter:

```
capabilities: ["CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM"]
```

and second there were some internal problems that caused the stack set to fail.

Comment: when you say there was some internal problems - can you elaborate further on these problems and how you identified what they were?

Answer (score 0):

I had same error, and I localized it setting disable_rollback to true. So I was able to open cloudformation->StackSets-> 'my stack set' and check the details of the issue. If you use sam for deploying, you can add this parameter to the command:

```
--no-rollback
```